# React.useEffect stack execution prevents parent from setting defaults

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have attached a simplified example that demonstrates my issue:

https://codesandbox.io/s/reactusehook-stack-issue-piq15

I have a parent component that receives a configuration, of which screen should be rendered. the rendered screen should have control over the parent appearance. In the example above I demonstrated it with colors. But the actual use case is flow screen that has next and back buttons which can be controlled by the child.

in the example I define common props for the screens:

```
type GenericScreenProps = {
  setColor: (color: string) => void;
};
```

I create the first screen, that does not care about the color (parent should default)

```
const ScreenA = (props: GenericScreenProps) => {
  return <div>screen A</div>;
};
```

I create a second screen that explicitly defines a color when mounted

```
const ScreenB = ({ setColor }: GenericScreenProps) => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("child");
    setColor("green");
  }, [setColor]);
  return <div>screen B</div>;
};
```

I create a map to be able to reference the components by an index

```
const map: Record<string, React.JSXElementConstructor<GenericScreenProps>> = {
  0: ScreenA,
  1: ScreenB
};
```

and finally I create the parent, that has a button that swaps the component and sets the default whenever the component changes

```
const App = () => {
  const [screenId, setScreenId] = useState(0);
  const ComponentToRender = map[screenId];
  const [color, setColor] = useState("red");
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("parent");
    setColor("red"); // default when not set should be red
  }, [screenId]);
  const onButtonClick = () => setScreenId((screenId + 1) % Object.keys(map).length)
  return (
    <div>
      <button style={{ color }} onClick={onButtonClick}>
        Button
      </button>
      <ComponentToRender setColor={setColor} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

In this example, the default color should be `red`, for screen A. and `green` for the second screen.

However, the color stays `red` because `useEffect` is using a stack to execute the code. if you run the code you will see that once the button clicked there will be `child` followed by `parent` in log.

I have considered the following solution, but they are not ideal:

- each child has to explicitly define the color, no way to enforce it without custom lint rules
- convert the parent into a react class component, there has to be a hooks solution

This might be an anti-pattern where child component controls how its parent behave, by I could not identify a way of doing that without replicating the parent container for each screen. the reason I want to keep a single parent is to enable transition between the screens.

Comment: The button switches the component from A to B to A. What is the color doing exactly? How is it supossed to behave?

Comment: when on component A the container should reset the color to `red`. when navigating to component B the screen should override the `red` into `green`

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the problem correctly, there is no need to pass down `setColor` to the children. Making expressions more explicit might make a bit longer code, but I think it helps in readability. As what you shared is a simplified example, please let me know if it fits your real case:

```
const ScreenA = () => {
    return <div>screen A</div>;
};

const ScreenB = () => {
    return <div>screen B</div>;
};

const App = () => {
    const [screen, setScreen] = useState<"a" | "b">("a");
    const [color, setColor] = useState<"red" | "green">("red");
    const onButtonClick = () => {
        if (screen === "a") {
            setScreen("b");
            setColor("green");
        } else {
            setScreen("a");
            setColor("red");
        }
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <button style={{ color }} onClick={onButtonClick}>
                Button
            </button>
            {screen === "a" ? <ScreenA /> : <ScreenB />}
        </div>
    );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: That is a valid solution for the example. However, I am not sure that is the right approach for my use case. as those "Screens" are developed by other teams. I prefer to keep the developers bound the the api exposed by the container. otherwise each new screen would add more complexity to the parent. which is what I am trying to avoid

Comment: @KirillKulakov I could imagine. Which is exactly the requisite? That color can be changed from the children? If so why simply passing `setColor` is not valid?

Comment: Currently the container is a step controller that can render a step and the controls assisted with it such as: should the menu be visible on this step, should the buttons be enabled, what do the buttons do when clicked. if the controller receives an update that a screen step should be changed it transitions to another step. keeping the controls in place

Comment: @KirillKulakov then I guess you could define an object with the different steps, which indicate which controls each activates/deact.: `{ step1: { control1_active: true, control2_active: false }, step2: {...}}`. Then have a state in the parent that keeps track of the current "step". This state, which only changes the name of the step, is the one passed to the children. Then, using the current step as `key` for the steps object, the parent displays those controls. Does it make sense?

Comment: Unfortunately, this would work as the controls state has to be dynamic. the interaction within the screen will affect the state of the controls. For instance, the next button is disabled until the checkbox inside the step is checked